# Python dataframe to_cvs() how to remove the tab at the beginning of the output text file

Tags: python, pandas

I want to save a pandas DataFrame into a text file and make it R-friendly for later analysis. I used `dataframe.to_cvs(filename, sep = '\t')`. But I noticed that the output file begins with a tab, which is not quite readable for `read.table()` in R.
I used `od -c filename`, and it showed like this:

```
\t 1 2 3 4 \t 5 6 7 8 \t 1 2 3 ...
```

Is there any way to remove the tab at the beginning? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it seems that this has to do with the index.

Try this one on for size:

```
dataframe.to_csv(filename, sep = '\t', index_label=False)
```

The docs are stating this:

> index_labelstr or sequence, or False, default None
> Column label for index column(s) if desired. If None is given, and header and index are True, then the index names are used. A sequence should be given if the object uses MultiIndex. If False do not print fields for index names. **Use index_label=False for easier importing in R.**

I am on Windows so I cannot use the `od` command to check.

Comment: Great, please accept is as the answer so others may find it more easily as well :)